# Updating to mailchimp api v2.0

Tags: api, mailchimp

I am working on a mailchimp plugin that integrates with mailchimp using the v 1.3 api. I'm trying to update it to v2.0 but other than changing the api version in the callback URL, I'm not sure what else needs to be changed. Version 1.3 seems to still work even tho it has been deprecated, but I'd like to update it to 2.0 anyway.

What steps would one have to take to update the entire api? I'm sure there are/have been functions that were deprecated for 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are going to have to review the differences between the API specifications for v2.0 and v1.3 -- and look at which functions you call to see what you will need to change.

[Mailchimp v2.0 specifications](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/)

[Mailchimp v1.3 specifications](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/)

Comment: Thanks! I actually went through and checked out the provided PHP MailChimp API Wrapper. The previous author was using the MCAPI v1.3 wrapper. After implementing the new wrapper it was a matter of re-writing the already coded functions to follow the new 2.0 method structure.

Comment: Glad this helped!  What use case are you using with the api access to MailChimp? (Just curious)

Comment: Im not 100% sure I understand what you mean by use case. But I am re-writing a WordPress plugin that my company had written a few months back. I added a few features and updated it to the 2.0 api. In regards to the wrapper, I went with the mail chimp provided php wrapper. After a little modification I had a connection to mailchimp